# HTML&CSS To PDF utility

Tags: php, pdf

I've been looking for useful PHP utility in order to provide PDF report from html&css.
First I've tried FPDF which didn't work fine.
Later I've tried MPDF, which was better then FPDF but still messed up and returned empty pages because it could hardly handle large chunks of html data.

Could you please recommend on a useful,easy to use and easy to implement PDF utility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948

Answer (score 1):

I've used [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) in the past and found it a lot better than FPDF.

It has functionality for [HTML + CSS](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps) and lots of examples

Comment: thanks for sharing.. their examples look nice (found them here http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)

Comment: Hey, thanks for recommending on TCPDF.
I've installed it and it worked well, but i'm still facing the some problem that came up on MPDF - instead of output I only see blank page (only the header is well displayed). I am able to output some data, but while trying to display tables I see nothing

Answer (score 0):

you could use html2fpdf (based also on fpdf but extended for html support) but don't expect advanced css support